# How to implement Google Adsense on VuePress?

Tags: adsense, vuepress

Is there a way to easily implement Google Adsense in VuePress? The resources I've found only provides a 'how-to' for [Vue only](https://github.com/mazipan/vue-google-adsense).

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following lines to your **config.js** file

```
head: [
    ['script', { src: "//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" }],
    ['script', {}, 
    '(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({  google_ad_client: <your code here>,  enable_page_level_ads: true });'],
],
```

This will add the code inside your head tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the config directly, there is a plugin for using Google Adsense

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuepress-plugin-google-adsense

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      'vuepress-plugin-google-adsense',
      {
        'google_ad_client': '', // ca-pub-0000000000000000
        'enable_page_level_ads': true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```